# webpack-dev-server acting weird

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I've encountered a problem working with `webpack-dev-server` wherein the terminal output states that the bundle is valid, and when I request my app on my server (ie `localhost`), everything works as it should. When I request my app from another host, however, I am unable to load `bundle.js`, and I get a `Network connection was lost` error on Safari and a `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` on Chrome. To explain further, if I go to `http://url/public/bundle.js` on my server, I get `bundle.js`, and if I try to do the same on my local machine, I get the errors. Here's my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './assets/jsx/modsoussi.jsx'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: 'http://modsoussi.xyz:8080/public/',

    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015','react'] // react preset is needed in this case to avoid
                                                // unexpected token '<' error.
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    externals: {
        'react':'React'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['','.js','.jsx']
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean - "I request my app from another host"? I mean what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If I request the app from a machine that's not the server, like my local computer, I get the errors. If I ssh into my server, and make the request from there, it works.

Comment: Are you actually trying to use webpack-dev-server to serve your code on a server? If not, what are you using to serve it?

Comment: webpack-dev-server is supposed to bundle my code into `bundle.js` and then serve it. But it doesn't seem to be doing so. I'm only able to get `bundle.js` if I make a request from my server to my server, if I make a request from any other machine, I get an empty response from the server.